# Auto-mount CD/DVD drive to single, specific mount point every time?

Tags: gnome, mount, automount

Currently, whenever I insert a CD or DVD into my DVD drive, it mounts to a location such as `/media/<LABEL>`, where `<LABEL>` is the arbitrary label assigned to the optical disc.

I remember, once upon a time, CD and DVD media being reliably located at /media/cdrom0 or something similar. Why was this changed? And how do I get this old behavior back for this drive?

I can understand this behavior for USB sticks. It makes sense for those. But not for CD/DVD media, in my opinion. For example, because of this, I have no way to configure Wine to point to my DVD drive, as the mount point changes with every single CD I insert.

**TL;DR: How do I make CD/DVD media always mount to `/media/cdrom0`?**

Comment: Another instance of this issue: http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-January/391226.html (replies begin at http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-January/391284.html)

Comment: Same issue here. To no avail.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one cdrom drive, add this line to your /etc/fstab:

`/dev/scd0  /media/cdrom0  udf,iso9660  user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0`

Make sure you edit it as root. Ie: `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.

The [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) has a really good article on this.

Comment: I tried this, but I got this error: `Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with: mount: mount point /media/cdrom0 does not exist`. After creating `/media/cdrom0` (using `sudo`), then it works, sort of. However, there's a problem. When GNOME auto-mounts the drive, my UID is set as the owner. This way, some random UID is the owner and I'm unable to read any of the files on the CD/DVD now. GNOME isn't currently relying on fstab, so I was hoping for a solution that uses GNOME's current way of handling auto-mounting so I can access the files without needing (gk)sudo.

Comment: Does it work if you change the line to: `/dev/scd0 /media/cdrom0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8,umask=0222 0 0`?

Comment: It doesn't change much... Before the umask addition: `-rwx------ 1 503 dialout    2217232 2009-10-12 19:55 Installer.exe
` After the umask addition: `-r-x------ 1 503 dialout    2217232 2009-10-12 19:55 Installer.exe
`

Comment: You can try to change the ownership of `/media/cdrom0` run something like `sudo chown [your user name]:[your user name] /media/cdrom0`

Answer (score 2):

This problem occured to me when I upgraded Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04. Using Disk Utility I discovered that now the CD Drive is a device /dev/sr0, so I changed the line in /etc/fstab file which was earlier /dev/scd0 to /dev/sr0 and it worked for me.

PV