# Need permanent CDROM/DVD mountpoint for WINE

Tags: hardware, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-mount CD/DVD drive to single, specific mount point every time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25759/auto-mount-cd-dvd-drive-to-single-specific-mount-point-every-time)

I've been running Ubuntu on several machines for years now, and running windows software under Wine as needed. Even through upgrades, my 'desktop' sees the CDROM drive, even without a disc in it.

I would very much like my new 'server' to behave the same way.

Right now, the only reference to the disc is /media/ -- which means every time I change the disc, I have to quit my program, open wine configurator, find the new disc, assign it, apply changes, re-run my wine application, and carry on. It's quite laborious.

I've tried mounting /dev/sr0, but it says it can't because it's a 'special directory'. Anyway, if someone would point me in a good direction, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Bump! I've made no progress on this, perhaps it's a hardware issue - i.e. it doesn't my like i3 set up?